# My UI getting updated when all task done

Tags: c#, winforms

see my below code and tell me what is wrong there for which my UI is getting updated when all task finish but as per code it suppose to update label value when my routine is calling by task. what to change in my code.

say for example when DoSomething1 is getting called then label3 need to be updated and reflected before user.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    var token = Task.Factory.CancellationToken;

    var tasks = new[]
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew( DoSomething1,token,TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(DoSomething2,token,TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(DoSomething3,token,TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler)
    };
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    //var things = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    int x=0;
}

public void DoSomething1()
{
    //this.label3.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    //{
    //    this.label3.Text = "DoSomething1 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    //}));
    this.label3.Text = "DoSomething1 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

public void DoSomething2()
{
    //this.label4.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    //{
    //    this.label4.Text = "DoSomething2 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    //}));
    this.label4.Text = "DoSomething2 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

public void DoSomething3()
{
    //this.label5.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    //{
    //    this.label5.Text = "DoSomething3 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    //}));
    this.label5.Text = "DoSomething3 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199022) is correct, as far as it goes. Using `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` causes the scheduler that's being used to be one that always uses the current thread to run tasks. I.e. the UI thread. The tasks should be run with `Task.Run()` and without a specific scheduler (it will default to the thread pool scheduler). `BeginInvoke()` is one option for correctly accessing the `Label` objects.

However, it seems to me it would be better to fix all of the code so that it's more idiomatic in the current `async`/`await` paradigm. For example:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your original example didn't show how you used this value,
    // so I don't have anything in this example that uses it. But you
    // would probably want to pass it to the "DoSomething..." methods
    // so that those methods can then pass the token to whatever async
    // operation they are actually doing. See additional comment below.
    var token = Task.Factory.CancellationToken;

    var tasks = new[]
    {
        DoSomething1(),
        DoSomething2(),
        DoSomething3()
    };
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    int x=0;
}

public async Task void DoSomething1()
{
    this.label3.Text = "DoSomething1 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    // replace with `Task.Run()` or whatever already-asynchronous
    // operation you need/want. Likewise in the other methods.
    // Don't forget to pass the CancellationToken to these methods,
    // and then on to whatever tasks you actually are running.
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

public async Task DoSomething2()
{
    this.label4.Text = "DoSomething2 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

public async Task DoSomething3()
{
    this.label5.Text = "DoSomething3 -- " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: u did not use or pass `uiScheduler and token` then why u create this?

Comment: Using `uiScheduler` was the main thing wrong with your code in the first place. It's not possible to use it and still have the code work. Your code didn't show you actually _using_ `token` (you passed it to `StartNew()` but your own code never used it, so your tasks can't be cancelled), so there's no way for me to know how it should be used in any alternate example, so I just left it out. As you can see from the comment in my code example though, if you want to be able to cancel the task, you will have to pass it to the task you want to be able to cancel.

Comment: if i comment this line then what will happen `TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();`

Comment: You can safely omit that line. It's there only because it was left over from my copy/paste from your original code. I will edit the post to clarify.

Comment: i guess we can omit this line too because it is not used in program. `var token = Task.Factory.CancellationToken;`

Comment: Yes, if you choose not to make your tasks cancellable, then of course you also don't need to use a token. (Your code was using the default token anyway, so it's just there for code that expects _some_ token value to be passed).

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm unfamiliar with `TaskScheduler` it looks like it's scheduling all of your tasks on the UI thread.

Don't use a scheduler, then to do your UI updates use something like:

```
        var threadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        this.BeginInvoke(() => {
            this.label3.Text = "DoSomething1 -- " + threadId ;
        });
```

This will invoke your UI operations onto the UI thread.

Comment: This is correct and useful. But IMHO it's better to go all the way with `async`/`await` and then there's no need for things like `BeginInvoke()` (at least not in this example). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40199065)

Comment: i use BeginInvoke() but i try to know how can i update UI without BeginInvoke()